# Java - mkdir() not writing directory

Tags: java, mkdir

I am trying to create a directory but it seems to fail every time? I have checked that it is not a permission issue too, I have full permission to write to that directory. Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

```
private void writeTextFile(String v){
    try{

        String yearString = convertInteger(yearInt);
        String monthString = convertInteger(month);
        String fileName = refernce.getText();
        File fileDir = new File("C:\\Program Files\\Sure Important\\Report Cards\\" + yearString + "\\" + monthString);
        File filePath = new File(fileDir + "\\"+ fileName + ".txt");
        writeDir(fileDir);
        // Create file 
        FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(filePath);
        try (BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream)) {
            out.write(v);
        }
    }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

private void writeDir(File f){
    try{
         if(f.mkdir()) { 
             System.out.println("Directory Created");
        } else {
        System.out.println("Directory is not created");
        }
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static String convertInteger(int i) {
    return Integer.toString(i);
}

Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
public int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
public int yearInt = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Here is the output:

```
Directory is not created
Error: C:\Program Files\Sure Important\Report Cards\2012\7\4532.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's possibly because `File.mkdir` creates the directory only if the parent directory exists.
Try using [`File.mkdirs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29) which creates all the necessary directories.

Here's the code which worked for me.

```
private void writeDir(File f){
    try{
         if(f.mkdirs()) { 
             System.out.println("Directory Created");
        } else {
        System.out.println("Directory is not created");
        }
    } catch(Exception e){
            //  Demo purposes only.  Do NOT do this in real code.  EVER.
            //  It squashes exceptions ...
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The only change I made was to change `f.mkdir()` to `f.mkdirs()` and it worked

Comment: Cheers that seems to be the problem, I will accept the answer when it alows me to :) THANKS!!!

Comment: Since the "dynamic" part of the pathname has two directories, I'd say this theory is pretty good ...

Comment: I copied your code, changed it to mkdirs() and it worked. Editing to include relevant code

Comment: thank god i found this :)

Answer (score 8):

I think that [@La bla bla](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12127002/139985) has nailed it, but just for completeness, here are all of the things that I can think of that *could* cause a call to `File.mkdir()` to fail:

- A syntax error in the pathname; e.g. an illegal character in a file name component
- The directory to contain the final directory component does not exist.
- There is already something with that name.
- You don't have permission to create a directory in the parent directory
- You don't have permission to do a lookup in some directory on the path
- The directory to be created is on a read-only file system.
- The file system gave a hardware error or network related error.

(Obviously, some of these possibilities can be quickly eliminated in the context of this question ...)

Comment: WARNING FOR WINDOWS7.   I just wasted hours discovering that if a file name contains any directory part which is one of Window7 legacy words (that is : CON,PRN,AUX,CLOCK$,NUL,COM1-COM9,LPT1-LPT9... as we all knew... didn't  we? ) then mkdirs will fail without warning or apparent logical explanation.  Found under Java 7 b51 - it may not affect other versions of Java or  other programming languages. It does not affect the DOS cmd shell.