# File.mkdirs() doesn't work all the time

Tags: java

I am trying to create a directory using `File.mkdirs()`. However, it seems to behave strange: sometimes it creates the directory, but other times, **it silently ignores** the creation of directory.

Earlier I was useing mkdir() but in one of the articles, I read that using mkdirs() would solve the issue. However, it seems not. Any help?

This code is running on a windows machine.

**CODE:**

```
File myDir = new File(dirPath);

try{
      myDir.mkdirs();
   } 
   catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any exceptions?

Comment: What is in the `dirPath`? Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126987/java-mkdir-not-writing-directory

Comment: There are lots of reasons that might not work, like not having appropriate security rights

Comment: if he does not have security permissions `SecurityException` will be thrown: *If a security manager exists and its SecurityManager.checkRead(java.lang.String) method does not permit verification of the existence of the named directory and all necessary parent directories; or if the SecurityManager.checkWrite(java.lang.String) method does not permit the named directory and all necessary parent directories to be created*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a) You should check mkdirs return value; if false dirs were not created

b) It's better to use 1.7's java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories which will either create all dirs or will throw an exception with explanation why it failed

Answer (score 3):

According to the [File API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs()) signature of `mkdirs()` is

> public boolean mkdirs()

So you just have to check if the dir has been created...

```
File myDir = new File(dirPath);

try{
      if (!myDir.mkdirs()) {
          // error here
      }
   } 
   catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not silently. According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs()):

```
mkdirs returns true if and only if the directory was created; false otherwise
```