# Why is FileWriter not creating a new file ? FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, file-io, filewriter

So I have a code snippet as follows. Im trying to find out why it throws a FileNotFoundException.

```
File file= new File (WORKSPACE_PATH+fname);
FileWriter fw;
if (file.exists())
{
     fw = new FileWriter(file,true);//if file exists append to file. Works fine.
}
else
{
     fw = new FileWriter(file);// If file does not exist. Create it. This throws a FileNotFoundException. Why? 
}
```

Comment: What system are you working on?

Comment: Sorry for the noise guys. I had the wrong version. `git-pull` fixed it.Indeed the problem was with WORKSPACE_PATH

Comment: this should be reopened, this is the first result on google, and the referenced https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767117/why-filewriter-doesnt-create-a-new-file problem is permissions, not directory creation. I'd like to add an answer using the `Path` API.

Answer (score 7):

Using concatenation when creating the File won't add the necessary path separator.

```
File file = new File(WORKSPACE_PATH, fname);
```

Comment: He does mention that opening for appending works fine though?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a separator (Windows : `\` and Unix : `/`, you can use `File.separator` to get the system's separator) if `WORKSPACE_PATH` does not have one at its end, and manually creating the file with its parent directories might help.

Try this if `WORKSPACE_PATH` does not have a separator at its end :

```
File file = new File(WORKSPACE_PATH + File.separator + fname);
```

And add this before `fw = new FileWriter(file);`

```
file.mkdirs(); // If the directory containing the file and/or its parent(s) does not exist
file.createNewFile();
```

Comment: And how you know that his `WORKSPACE_PATH` doesn't contain the separator?

Comment: as he told append works fine that means no problem with the path of the file

Comment: Edited, I forgot to say that you don't need to add one if `WORKSPACE_PATH` already has one ><

Comment: Or you could use the two-arg form: `new File(WORKSPACE_PATH, fname)`

Answer (score 2):

This might work:

```
File file= new File (WORKSPACE_PATH+fname);
FileWriter fw;
if (file.exists())
{
   fw = new FileWriter(file,true);//if file exists append to file. Works fine.
}
else
{
   file.createNewFile();
   fw = new FileWriter(file);
}
```

Comment: throws an `IOException` at that line.

Comment: What is the IOException message details?

Comment: From what I can see, this should be fine - can you print the full `WORKSPACE_PATH+fname`, and confirm that it is trying to create it in the right place?

Comment: [This](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-append-content-to-file-in-java) does essentially what you're trying to do.